# iOS SKMaps not loading annotations (Xcode 6, Objective C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, skmaps

I'm having problems with SKMaps for iOS. It seems that it is not loading the annotations. It should display an annotation somewhere around the lake

[image]

Also on the initialization, it doesn't go to the specified region.

InitMap Method

```
-(void) initMap {
    /*
     self.mapView = [[SKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 
        CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame), CGRectGetHeight(self.view.frame))];
    */
    self.mapView = [[SKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:
        CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 238.0f, 157.0f)];

    self.mapView.autoresizingMask 
        = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

    // set initial coordinates
    // la mesa dam
    //_loc2DLamesaDam = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(14.7241845,121.085998);
    SKCoordinateRegion region;
    region.center = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(14.7241845,121.085998);
    region.zoomLevel = 17;

    self.mapView.visibleRegion = region;

    //[self.view addSubview:mapView];
    //show the compass
    self.mapView.settings.showCompass = YES;
    //hide the map scale
    self.mapView.mapScaleView.hidden = YES;
    self.mapView.settings.rotationEnabled = NO;
    self.mapView.settings.followUserPosition = YES;
    SKMapZoomLimits zoomLimits;
    zoomLimits.mapZoomLimitMax = 17;
    zoomLimits.mapZoomLimitMin = 10;
    self.mapView.settings.zoomLimits = zoomLimits;

    self.mapView.settings.headingMode = SKHeadingModeRotatingMap;

    [self determineMapStyle];

    [self addAnotation:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(14.7241845,121.085998) 
          annotationId:1
             imageName:nil
           imageHeight:0.0f
            imageWidth:0.0f
       skAnotationType:SKAnnotationTypePurple];
}
```

AddAnotation method

```
-(void)addAnotation:(CLLocationCoordinate2D) coordinate annotationId:(int) annotationId
        imageName:(NSString*)imageName imageHeight:(float) imageHeight imageWidth:(float) 
        imageWidth skAnotationType:(SKAnnotationType) skAnotationType {

[mapView removeAnnotationWithID:annotationId];

SKAnnotation *annotation = [SKAnnotation annotation];
annotation.identifier = annotationId;
annotation.location = coordinate; //CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(52.5237, 13.4137);
SKAnimationSettings *animationSettings = [SKAnimationSettings animationSettings];

if(imageName.length==0 || imageName == (id)[NSNull null])
{
    annotation.annotationType = skAnotationType;      
} else {
    //Annotation with view
    //create our view
    UIImageView *coloredView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:
        CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 128.0, 128.0)];
    coloredView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];

    //create the SKAnnotationView
    SKAnnotationView *view = [[SKAnnotationView alloc] initWithView:coloredView 
        reuseIdentifier:@"viewID"];

    //set the custom view
    annotation.annotationView = view;

}
[self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation withAnimationSettings:animationSettings];
//[mapView addAnnotation:viewAnnotation withAnimationSettings:animationSettings];}
```

Comment: are you using 2.5 SDK?

Comment: Hi Sylvia, many thanks for the reply. The folder says SKMaps_iOS_2, I just hit download from Skobbler couple weeks ago. Should I get the latest build 2.5.1?

Comment: 2.5.1 is compatible with Swift 2.0 (the stable release provided with XCode 7)

Comment: 2.5.1 is compatible with Swift 2.0 (the stable release provided with XCode 7)
2.5.0 used the Swift version available in April 2015 (which was still a "in development version") - I recommend that you get the 2.5.1 build with XCode 7

Comment: Hi Ando, I got the 2.5.1 and so far it is still the same.... it's slower than the previous release also. I'm running on iOS 8.2 btw and using Xcode 6

Comment: is the issue still present using the XCode 7?

Comment: @ClearskiesPH can you replicate your scenario in the demo project (at least the problematic parts)? If yes, please provide a link to the modified project so that we can take a look.

Comment: @ClearskiesPH also the code  SKCoordinateRegion region;
    region.center = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(14.7241845,121.085998);
    region.zoomLevel = 17;
        self.mapView.visibleRegion = region;
works in the demo project - please try it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the visible region works, as well as adding an annotation with a custom view. This is the code that works in our demo project:

```
UIImageView *customAnnotationView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)]; 
    customAnnotationView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor]; 
    customAnnotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"santa"]; //"santa.png" was added to resources 

    SKAnnotationView *annotationView = [[SKAnnotationView alloc] initWithView:customAnnotationView reuseIdentifier:@"reusableIdentifier"]; 

    SKAnnotation *annotation = [SKAnnotation annotation]; 
    annotation.identifier = 123456; 
    annotation.location = region.center; 
    annotation.annotationView = annotationView; 

    [self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation withAnimationSettings:[SKAnimationSettings animationSettings]];
```